# Spreadsheet rename event with apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

Is it possible to listen to "Spreadsheet renamed" events?

The corresponding [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) has changeType equal to 'OTHER'. It works when the change is renaming a sheet, but doesn't work when the whole spreadsheet is renamed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run a function on sheet rename, no. You can do it from a Spreadsheet-bound script, but you need to set some properties and cascade the triggers. This is a really rough working example:

```js
// Globals
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var name = ss.getName();

// Each edit, check for a rename
function onEdit() {

  // Grab the stored name from opening
  var setName = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty("name");

  // Get the current name of the sheet.
  var currentName = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName();

  // If it doesn't match, there's been a rename. Log and reset the stored name.
  if(setName != currentName) {
    Logger.log("Renamed from " + setName + " to " + currentName);
    PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("name", currentName)
    // do something else
  }
}

// Store the name when the sheet is opened
function onOpen() {
  var currentName = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("name", name);
  Logger.log(currentName.getProperty("name"));
}
```